# Открытие окна мини браузера на странице

Tags: javascript, html

Мне надо открыть на странице браузера новую страницу мини-браузера. Это, возможно, немного похоже на htmlacademy.

Хотелось бы, чтобы окошко страницы делилось на саму страницу с контентом, а справа подгружалась другая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это называется `iframe`  http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe ..... а выглядит он как минибраузер, потому, что применены `css` стили для оформления так

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите именно так, как на `htmlacademy`, то вам нужно воспользоваться тегом 
`iframe`

Тег `<iframe>` создает плавающий фрейм, который находится внутри обычного документа, он позволяет загружать в область заданных размеров любые другие независимые документы.

Основной его атрибут `src` - в нем указывается путь к файлу, содержимое которого будет загружаться во фрейм.

Все остальное (внешний вид, как будто это новое окно браузера) достигается за счет стилизации этого фрейма и оберток в виде дивов вокруг него:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  vertical-align: top;
  }

#col1 {
  width: 150px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div id="col1">
  Колонка слева <br />
  Колонка слева <br />
  Колонка слева <br />
  Колонка слева <br />
</div>
<div>
  <iframe class="browser" id="preview" src="http://www.eldorado.com.ua/" width="400" height="450"></iframe>
</div>
```

Вот примерно как это выглядит в исходном коде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы скопировали разметку и стили с сайта `htmlacademy` целиком в свой ответ. Так делать нельзя - это нарушение авторского права. Весь код, который публикуется в ответах, попадает под действие модифицированной лицензии MIT - но так можно поступать только со своим кодом!

Comment: @PavelMayorov в таком случае будет непонятно до конца как стили влияют. А так было наглядно..но вы правы....изменил только на саму суть